# Using Tkinter with Openshift

Tags: python, openshift

I would like to deploy a Python3 app that uses tkinter on OpenShift.  I added the following to setup.py: `install_requires=["Tcl==8.6.4"]`.  When I ran `git push` I received the following error:

> Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('Tcl==8.6.4').

Can anyone provide the correct syntax, distribution package name and version?

Comment: Does Openshift find it if you don't use the version number in your install requires? If it does what version did it find?

Comment: you aren't going to be able to serve tkinter applications via a web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bryan has answered the question.  Tkinter will not work with WSGI.  A web framework such as Django must be used.